# Does reducing the key travel distance in a keyboard help prevent computer users from getting repetitive strain injuries (RSI)?

Tags: tendinopathy, computers, repetitive-strain-injury

The vast majority of desktop computer keyboards have around 4 mm of key travel distance, which is about twice longer than the key travel distance on most laptops (and flat keyboards a.k.a. thin keyboards a.k.a. low-profile keyboards).

Does reducing the key travel distance in a keyboard always help prevent computer users from getting repetitive strain injuries (RSI)?

I am mostly interested in epicondylitis (epicondylopathy).